# Check If There Is Sufficient Memory On SD Card Programmatically

Tags: java, android

My app is saving files on the SD Card but before I save the files I need to check if there is free memory. I need a to check how much free memory is on the SD Card.

Something like:

```
if(MemoryCard.getFreeMemory()>20Mb)
{
    saveFiles();
}
else
{
    Toast.makeText(this, "Not enough memory", 100).show();
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

from: http://groups.google.com/group/android-developers/browse_thread/thread/ecede996463a4058

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)stat.getBlockSize() * (long)stat.getBlockCount();
long megAvailable = bytesAvailable / 1048576;
```

Comment: you can use stat.getAvailableBytes(); for android 4.3+ (API 18+)

Answer (score 7):

```
StatFs class
```

you can use here, provide the path for your internal and external directory and calculate the total, free and avialable space.

```
StatFs memStatus = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = (long)memStatus.getBlockSize() * (long)memStatus.getAvailableBlocks();
```

See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/StatFs.html) for more details. `bytesAvailable` is in bytes you can convert it in to which ever format you want.

Comment: How to check the available space on Google Drive programatically from android app

Answer (score 1):

**For Android 4.3+ (API Level: 18+)**

```
StatFs stat = new StatFs(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath());
long bytesAvailable = getAvailableBytes();
```